# Git rebasing conflicts with clean branch and how to handle them?

Tags: git

I have ran into this situation a few times and I am curious how others handle this.

Let's say I have two branches on the remote server that look like this:

```
branchA: a123-->b123-->c123-->e123-->f123

branchB: a123-->d123-->b123-->c123
```

Let's assume that `d123` was committed  before `b123` and `c123` on `branchB`.  At some point, we need to rebase `branchA` onto `branchB` because it has work that `branchB` needs.  A colleague does that, cleans up the conflicts, all is well and `branchB` is pushed back up to the remote server.  My local branch now is clean and looks something like `branchB` used to look:

```
local branchB: a123-->d123-->b123-->c123
```

Naturally, I need to rebase what's in the remote server from `branchB` onto my local `branchB` so I have the work.  Sometimes though, I run into a situation where I have conflicts in my local branch and git asks me to go through each of them, as rebasing usually works.  This is because I don't actually have the history from `branchA` that was rebased into `branchB` by a colleague.

The problem is that I know all of the work I have done up until this point is in the remote `branchB` and there are no conflicts to actually fix.  Going through each of them would be a waste of time.  I just want the history that's on the remote `branchB` to replace my local history.

Scouring the Internet there seems to be a few different solutions to the issue but I am not quite sure which one is best or Linus approved if you will.  I actually am not sure if I have even found the answer I am looking for.

Some answers say that I should be using a rebase and using the `theirs` option or picking a different strategy.  I believe some answers say that the `--skip` is appropriate here... However it looks like `git --skip` *literally* skips commits in some cases.  Also, it looks like using the `theirs` option like `git rebase -X theirs` actually rewrites the SHAs for me in some cases which throws the history out of whack, which is not what I want.

So, my question is how would I reconcile the history on my local branch with the history on the remote branch when:

- Everything in my local branch is already in the remote branch?
- My branch is clean, has no pending changes and there really aren't any conflicts to fix?
- Really all I want is to replace what's in my local branch history with what's in the remote branch history?

Answer (score 1):

> Really all I want is to replace what's in my local branch history with what's in the remote branch history

Just do a hard reset:

```
git checkout branchB
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/branchB
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  Any advice on how to do this otherwise?